# Get Java Object properties in Javascript function

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, arraylist

I am getting an arraylist of objects from Java class and I want to pass this arraylist to a javascript function and get each object's properties inside the javascript function.

Please help me how to extract the value of the attributes inside the object.

Following is the code which I am using

```
`<script type="text/javascript">
var stats=new Array();
var i=0;
<%JobStats jobstat=new JobStats();
ArrayList<JobStats> stats=jobstat.Consolidate();
for(int i=0;i<stats.size();i++)
{
%>
stats[i]="<%=stats.get(i)%>";
i=i+1;
<%}%>
loadstats(stats);
</script>`
/* Javascript function*/
var array=new Array();
function loadstats(stats)
{

    array=stats[0];
    for(var key in array)
        {
        document.write(array[key]);
        }

}
```

Comment: You can use http://json-taglib.sourceforge.net/index.html to render your java objects as json via jstl. Or you could serialize your Java object to a Json string in the servlet.

Answer (score 0):

One of the ways to comunicate betweet Java and javascript is using JSON.
Javascript supports JSON natively in most modern browsers and in Java you can use [Simple JSON](http://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)

You can transfer JSON Objects an Arrays between both languages.